Multiple plots with different hatch features in the same figure in matplotlib
I want to have multiple contourf plots with different hatch features in the same figure.
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import numpy as np

x=np.arange(0,10,0.1)
y=np.arange(0,10,0.1)

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)

Z=np.where(xx>yy, 1, 0)

hatch_color=mcolors.to_rgba("green")
plt.rcParams['hatch.linewidth'] = 2
plt.rcParams['hatch.color'] = hatch_color
plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z,levels=[0.5, 1],hatches=["\\"],colors='red')
plt.show()
plt.clf()

Z=np.where(xx<yy, 1, 0)

hatch_color=mcolors.to_rgba("blue")
plt.rcParams['hatch.linewidth'] = 10
plt.rcParams['hatch.color'] = hatch_color
plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z,levels=[0.5, 1],hatches=["\\"],colors='red')
plt.show()
plt.clf()

The code above produces two plots
firstplot
second plot
I used plt.rcParams to set the hatch properties like color or linewidth. However these changes are global and concern all the hetches in the figure.
I would like to produce these two contourf plots with different hetches in one figure. How can I achieve that? I expect that one can change the hatch properties locally instead of using  plt.rcParams , but I can't figure out how.

I think you don't want the intermediate plt.show() and plt.clf(), they basically remove what you already plotted (see the "Notes" section here for more about that).
Without them, at least the different colors seem to be displayed correctly, but the linewidths are still the same. It seems like only the value of 'hatch.linewidth' at the time of rendering is used...
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import numpy as np

x=np.arange(0,10,0.1)
y=np.arange(0,10,0.1)

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)

Z=np.where(xx>yy, 1, 0)

hatch_color=mcolors.to_rgba("green")
plt.rcParams['hatch.linewidth'] = 2
plt.rcParams['hatch.color'] = hatch_color
plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z,levels=[0.5, 1],hatches=["\\"],colors='red')

Z=np.where(xx<yy, 1, 0)

hatch_color=mcolors.to_rgba("blue")
plt.rcParams['hatch.linewidth'] = 10
plt.rcParams['hatch.color'] = hatch_color
plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z,levels=[0.5, 1],hatches=["\\"],colors='red')

plt.savefig("two_hatch_hydra.png")
plt.show()


matplotlib contourf with two different hatch colors

Exactly, hatch.linewidth is the issue. Thus I made two separate plots to illustrate the problem.
